# How to transpose multiple columns' cell in a single row using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following sample data in four columns ID, Name, Age, Salary, Country

```
ID: 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3
Name: David, Peter, Alex, Kevin, Steve, Morty
Age: 30, 35, 40, 20, 25, 35
Salary: 3000, 2000, 5000, 1500, 2000, 3000
Country: USA, UK, Germany, France, UK, USA
```

What I want to arrange data in each row and column is as follows.

```
Row_1: col_1, col_2, col_3, col_4, col_5, col_6, col_7, col_8, col_9, col_10, col_11, col_12, col_13
Row-2: 1, David, 30, 3000, USA, Peter, 35, 2000, UK, Nan, Nan, Nan, Nan
Row_3: 2, Alex, 40, 5000, Germany, Nan, Nan, Nan, Nan, Nan, Nan, Nan, Nan
Row_4: 3, Kevin, 20, 1500, France, Steve, 25, 2000, UK, Morty, 35, 3000, USA
```

It is noted that Some of the columns do not have any value, therefore **Nan** is written there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the one possible solution which you can try:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3],
                  'Name': ['David', 'Peter', 'Alex', 'Kevin', 'Steve', 'Morty'],
                  'Age': [30, 35, 40, 20, 25, 35],
                  'Salary': [3000, 2000, 5000, 1500, 2000, 3000],
                  'Country': ['USA', 'UK', 'Germany', 'France', 'UK', 'USA']})
rows = df['ID'].unique()
num = max(df['ID'].value_counts())
num_of_cols = num * 4 + 1

ROWS = 3
COLS = 13
df1 = pd.DataFrame(index=np.arange(ROWS), columns=np.arange(COLS))

idx = 0
for i in rows:
  temp = df.loc[df['ID'] == i]
  a = [i]
  for index in range(0,len(temp)):
    a = a + temp.iloc[index,1:5].tolist()
  for j in range(len(a),num_of_cols):
    a.append('NaN')
  df1.loc[idx] = a
  idx = idx + 1

print(df1)
```

Output:

```
0      1   2     3        4      5    6     7    8      9    10    11   12
0  1  David  30  3000      USA  Peter   35  2000   UK    NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN
1  2   Alex  40  5000  Germany    NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN    NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN
2  3  Kevin  20  1500   France  Steve   25  2000   UK  Morty   35  3000  USA
```